# PHP: Объясните, пожалуйста, один момент в объектно-ориентированном программировании

Tags: php, классы, объекты

Пытался разобраться на примере класса, написанного другим программистом и увидел там такой синтаксис:

```
class Automobile
{
private XMLReader $transmission
private Autoloader $wheel

далее в классе методы
}
```

Что такое в данном случае XMLReader?

Я всегда в учебнике видел только подобное:

```
class Automobile
    {
    private $transmission
    private $wheel
    
    далее в классе методы
    }
```

Гугление результатов не дало, так как, даже не знаю, что искать. Подскажите, пожалуйста, если кто-нибудь знает. Может, XMLReader или Autoloader - это какой-то особый вид комментария к свойству объекта?

Comment: [Объявление типов](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.declarations.php) начиная с PHP 7.4.0, для свойств класса можно объявить тип. В Вашем случае это имя класса/интерфейса.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Начиная с версии *PHP 7.4* можно указывать типы не только у входных параметров методов и типы возвращаемых значений, но и у **[свойств класса](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.properties.php#language.oop5.properties.typed-properties)**

В типы входят следующие:

```
Тип Описание                Версия

Имя класса/интерфейса   -   Значение должно представлять собой instanceof заданного класса или интерфейса.   
self                    -   Значение должно представлять собой instanceof того же класса, в котором используется объявление типа. Может использоваться только в классах.     
parent                  -   Значение должно представлять собой instanceof родительского класса, в котором используется объявление типа. Может использоваться только в классах.   
array                   -   Значение должно быть типа array.     
callable                -   Значение должно быть корректным callable. Нельзя использовать в качестве объявления для свойств класса.  
bool                    -   Значение должно быть логического типа.   
float                   -   Значение должно быть числом с плавающей точкой.  
int                     -   Значение должно быть целым числом.   
string                  -   Значение должно быть строкой (тип string).   
iterable                -   Значение может быть либо массивом (тип array), либо представлять собой instanceof Traversable.  PHP 7.1.0
object                  -   Значение должно быть объектом (тип object). PHP 7.2.0
mixed                   -   Значение может иметь любой тип. PHP 8.0.0
```

В вашем случае это первый вариант:  "Имя класса/интерфейса"